# Oracle database monitoring for Web application

Tags: database, oracle, monitoring

We are building a J2EE web application on Oracle database. The underlying Oracle database is continuously hit by small but numerous online transactions in a day from the browser. At the same time, there are also ETL loads which hit the same database occasionally (once a day) to load large volumes of records (~1 to 2 million rows) and very rarely (once in a couple of months) the ETL load could even load ~10 million rows.

In this scenario, I would like to know what all Oracle database parameters (like Tablespace usage, Table locks, long running queries etc) might need to be monitored to identify problems in the database for OLTP & ETL transactions. We might be using a Database Profiler tool for this monitoring.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle Enterprise Manager is for free if you already have proper Oracle Enterpise DB licence.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B16240_01/doc/license.102/b40010.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I'm looking for the various factors that need to be monitored to identify problems. Based on these factors, I would like to choose any DB Profiler or OEM.